# Thumbnails in a web page

Tags: html, image, web, client-side

Suppose I display a web page with thumbnails of my pictures (all pictures are about 2M each).

In order to display the thumbnails, I can just use `img` tag with `max-height/max-width` attributes. However I am afraid the browser will download the original pictures and scale them down in the client. It looks like waste of resources.

Does it make sense to create the thumbnails in the server and load them rather than original pictures ?

On the other hand, what if user clicks on thumbnail and I should display the original picture ? Maybe I should load the original pictures in background and hide before the user clicks ...

What are the best practices to display images in a web page?

Comment: This depends entirely on how you're loading the larger images. Why would the browser load them instead of--or alongside--the thumbnails unless you told it to, either in your HTML or your popup script?

Comment: I see. I am asking what the best practices are.

Comment: Which, technically speaking, is a misuse of SO.

Comment: Why do you think it is a misuse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I display a web page with thumbnails of my pictures (all
>   pictures are about 2M each).
>
> In order to display the thumbnails, I can just use img tag with
>   max-height/max-width attributes. However I am afraid the browser will
>   download the original pictures and scale them down in the client. It
>   looks like waste of resources.

...it is. You usually prepare a thumbnail with the proper size and appropriate quality, sometimes more than one thumbnail even, for each image. Then you use some means (e.g. [ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)) to allow the customer to enlarge the image.

Since an image is 2M in size, and a thumbnail is usually 10-15 Kb, the site becomes much faster and more responsive. Also, you get less data traffic, which contributes to the overall speed (i.e. your customer is not slowed by his download, nor by other customers hogging the bandwidth).

> Does it make sense to create the thumbnails in the server and load them rather than original pictures ?

Absolutely. Bandwidth and site speed are worth much more than some disk space. There are several tools to do the resizing upon upload, depending on what your platform is. For PHP they're usually based on either ImageMagick (heavier, better quality) or GD library (faster, still good quality - more than enough for thumbnails).

You might even want to perform a resize/quality optimization on the *full sized* images.

For **very** large images, there are "pyramidation" scripts (e.g. Zoomify, AjaxZoom) that allow loading a large image piecewise, allowing to zoom in/out, pan and scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your tools. 
In php there is gd library, which help you to process images etc.

As long as I understood, The best practice for you would be to create thumbnails (through library), and load thumbnails in your webpage.. and once someone click on your thumbnail, link him to a popup/next page/any-jquery-photo-viewer to see the full photo.

I hope it explains what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It explains exactly what I need. Now I wonder if it is worth loading larger images in background alongside the thumbnails to display them quickly if needed.

Comment: I guess it is not required, 2M is a hurg size photo. 
only load image when its required.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I see that 2M images are really huge for the web.

Answer (score 1):

2 MB is *HUGE* for an image on the web, retina display or not!

Ideally you would scale the image down to a thumbnail, as browsers tend to do a poor job of scaling themselves.

Unless your images require a high level of resolution (I'm thinking something like medical imagery or engineering documents), you should also look a compressed image format like .PNG or .JPG.

However, your idea to display the full-size version when the thumbnail is clicked is a good one. I would also suggest that you pull in the large version via AJAX, which will reduce the amount of bandwidth your page will require. If you need to pull in large images, you should definitely pull them in "on-demand" with AJAX to reduce the payload of your page.

Answer (score 1):

Michael, if you have 2M image files, i dont think it good idea to load original images as thumbnails, the best practice in my expiriance to use some thumbnailer with imagemagic or GD libraries

1) create thumbnail on the fly with requested width and height

2) then save that thumnail to database

3) get image from db and send it to user

if user reques same size image see pt. 3) 
in other case see pt. 1)